# What pg_hba method corresponds to JDBC "crypt"?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, jdbc

The [JDBC connector documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/prepare.html) states that:

> The JDBC driver supports the trust, ident, password, md5, and crypt authentication methods.

The [documentation for pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), however, lists trust, ident, password, and md5 as supported methods - but not crypt. So what does "crypt" mean, here? SHA256?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go back to the [documentation of version 8.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) you will find it:

> `crypt`
>
> ```
>   Note: This option is recommended only for communicating with pre-7.2 clients.
> ```
>
> Require the client to supply a `crypt()`-encrypted password for authentication. `md5` is now recommended over `crypt`. See [Section 21.2.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PASSWORD) for details.

It seems like it was removed in the following versions, likely because being deemed as unsecure.